# How to create a “TV off” activity for Harmony Hub?

Tags: smart-home, logitech-harmony

I have a TCL TV that works fine with the Harmony Hub; it can turn the TV on or off reliably regardless of if it is already on or off (I don’t have the “toggle” issue some folks have).

The Harmony Activities seem to be designed to be turned on and off, but I want an activity the just sends the *Off signal* to the TV, independent of the state of the system — basically a fire-and-forget off switch. I can’t find a way to do this. It only wants to create on-and-off activities. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, Harmony Activities are a combination of actions with predefined "on" and "off" sequences.

If you want to control a device (i.e. send "on" and "off" commands separately), your solution will be the [KukuHarmony project](https://community.smartthings.com/t/release-kukuharmony-dth-and-smartapp-that-support-to-control-devices-in-logitech-harmony-using-harmony-api/87175/131). It's not the easiest thing to handle (as it requires a running server), but not rocket science either.